AgensGraph using jsonb_array_lengh to do comparison
I trying to do a comparison operator on an jsonb array in postgres.  I've tried using the command:
MATCH (s:"Type") WHERE jsonb_typeof(s."Array") > 1 RETURN s;
But I get the error 'cannot get array length of a non-array'
I tried to just use
MATCH (s:"Type") WHERE s."Array" > 1 RETURN s;
but it just returns all the arrays even one that have a length of one.  Does anyone know how I can do this comprasion?
